# R function for making a list from text file with each line as both the name and vector

Tags: r, shiny

I need help creating a list like the one below with a function that takes lines from a text file and converts them to list vectors with the names that are the same as the vector.

This list will be used to create a dictionary using the Quanteda package.

Text file example (input)

```
accident
accusation
advised
afraid
aftermath
```

Desired list example (output)

```
dictionary(list(accident = c("accident"),
            accusation = c("accusation"),
            advised = c("advised"),
            afraid = c("afraid"),
            aftermath = c("aftermath"))
```

My attempt -- however, I realize that am only making a single vector rather than a vector for each line item in the text file, so the number of items in the list and vector does not match.

```
thelist <- list(readLines(textfile))
names(thelist) <- str(readLines(textfile))
thedictionary <- dictionary(thelist)
```

In summary, how do I make a string vector for each item in the list to assign to names()?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: `thelist <- setNames(thelist, thelist)`? Or `as.list(setNames(.))`. You don't need to read the file twice!

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks! This does not give me any errors, however, now my output (a graph in a shiny app) doesn't show the graph but instead shows me a long text label with the list of words in a vector `("accident", "accusation", "advised", "afraid", "aftermath")` leading me to believe it is putting the entire list into one vector rather than a new vector for each word/line with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would be:

```
library(magrittr)

readLines("dict.txt") %>%
  as.list() %>%
  set_names(., .)
```

Returns

```
$accident
[1] "accident"

$accusation
[1] "accusation"

$advised
[1] "advised"

$afraid
[1] "afraid"

$aftermath
[1] "aftermath"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to clearly understand what you want, does this do the trick?

```
txt <- read.delim("SO_input.txt", header = F)
txt
# V1
# 1   accident
# 2 accusation
# 3    advised
# 4     afraid
# 5  aftermath
res <- vector("list", nrow(txt))
for(k in 1:nrow(txt))
  res[[k]] <- txt[k,1]
names(res) <- txt[,1]
res
# $accident
# [1] "accident"
# $accusation
# [1] "accusation"
# $advised
# [1] "advised"
# $afraid
# [1] "afraid"
# $aftermath
# [1] "aftermath"
```

If so, then you can replace the loop for instance with

```
res <- lapply(txt, as.list)[[1]]
names(res) <- txt[,1]
```

Comment: Yes, this output works and so does ktiu's solution which requires less code but loading another package! Thank you!

Comment: Actually the loop was an example, as you can see at the end of my answer this can be done with 2 lines as well.

Comment: Sorry! I think I saw the code before you posted the 2-line solution. Also works and is very elegant. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

There already is an accepted answer but here is an equivalent base R one.

```
thelist <- readLines("~/tmp/list.txt")
thelist <- thelist[thelist != ""]

as.list(setNames(thelist, thelist))
#$accident
#[1] "accident"
#
#$accusation
#[1] "accusation"
#
#$advised
#[1] "advised"
#
#$afraid
#[1] "afraid"
#
#$aftermath
#[1] "aftermath"
```